# How correct write parameter in powershell DSC

Tags: powershell, dsc

I create custom DSC Module.I have in DSC resource only two value, one of them is two dimension array:

```
node ("localhost")
   {
        ChangeXML ChangeValue
        {
            NameFile=$PathToXml #Enter path to input xml
            DownloadManagerCustomData = 
            @(
                @{
                        Node = 'some path';
                        Value = 'some value' 
                }#end of hash array

                @{
                        Node = 'some path';
                        Value = 'some value' 
                }#end of hash array 

            )#end of two dimensional array

        }
   }
```

And I create ChangeXML.schema.mof, which describe variable. So, I don't know how write array. Can you help me?

```
[ClassVersion("1.0"), FriendlyName("ChangeXML")]
class ChangeXML : OMI_BaseResource
{
  [Key] String NameFile;
  [Write] *Array?* DownloadManagerCustomData;
};
```

Comment: I'm not positive what the answer to your question is but just to be clear, what you create is an array of hashes. Not a two dimensional array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ClassVersion("1.0"), FriendlyName("ChangeXML")]
class ChangeXML : OMI_BaseResource
{
  [Key] String NameFile;
  [Write] EmbeddedInstance("MSFT_KeyValuePair")] String DownloadManagerCustomData[];
};
```

You could also use the `New-MofFile` function in [PowerShell.org's DSC repo](https://github.com/PowerShellOrg/DSC/tree/master/Tooling/DscDevelopment). It generates the MOF for you and works very well (full disclosure, I am not affiliated but I contributed a tiny bit of code to it).

### Edit

Fixed above code, and just realized that `New-MofFile` won't (currently) handle that, but it can be made to do so and I may patch it for that purpose when I get a chance.

Also I gave the MOF syntax for what you showed (an array of hashtables) rather than what you said (an array of arrays).